# How to input many letters and stop after a certain one (q or Q)?

Tags: c++, macos

I was assigned a homework to input as many letters as the user wants and stop after input q or Q. Then the programs should output how many vowels there were in such string. We're supposed to use _getche() function but I have MacBook so it doesn't work.

I've tried making conio.h. 
I've tried also using cin.get() and getchar() but none work.

Comment: `cin.get()` will read one character from the console, so that’s a good start. If you can’t get it to work, show the code.

Comment: conio.h is only for Windows. ncurses is a similar library for Linux and Mac. But there also big differences.

Comment: Virtual machine it up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream> // getchar(), std::cout
#include <cctype> // tolower()

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (;;) // infinite loop
    {
        char c = getchar(); // read a single char from stdin
        if (tolower(c) == 'q') // if input is 'q' or 'Q'
            break; // break out of the loop
        // check for vowel here
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "You typed in " << count << " vowels!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`__getche()` is not a standard function and `conio.h` is not a standard header. The usual way of doing this is:

```
int main() {
    int ch;
    int vowel_count = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != 'q' && ch != 'Q' && ch != EOF) {
       vowl_count += is_vowel(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i think you need it:

```
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool h = true;
    while(h){
        char ch;
        ch = getche();
        if(ch=='q' || ch == 'Q'){
           h = false; 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: <condo.h> is not standard C nor standard C++. Same for `getche()`. If you’re going to post answers that use such non-standard stuff you should indicate which platforms support it. Even better, propose portable solutions.